# Using same ROI/Signature for classifying spatially different rasters?

Tags: qgis, classification, image

Using QGIS SCP Plugin, I have classified a raster of a state.

Can I use the same ROI/signatures to classify rasters of other states?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].